# trying to bind input element to data value in vue page

Tags: vue.js

I have this table that you can see below. iam trying to bind the input element to the "project_settings" object values that you also can see below. Depending on the checkbox is checked or not the values inside project_settings object should change. But i get these 2 error whenever i click the input element that is a switch. It works like a checkbox:

```
error1: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_settings' of null"

error2: TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_settings' of null
at callback (app.js:78643)
at invokeWithErrorHandling (app.js:81219)
at VueComponent.invoker (app.js:81544)
at invokeWithErrorHandling (app.js:81219)
at VueComponent.Vue.$emit (app.js:83245)
at VueComponent.Vue.<computed> [as $emit] (backend.js:1793)
at VueComponent.updateInput (app.js:73355)
at invokeWithErrorHandling (app.js:81219)
at HTMLInputElement.invoker (app.js:81544)
at HTMLInputElement.original._wrapper (app.js:86903)
```

What can i do about this? Se my vue code below

```
data() {
 return {
  project_settings: {
    resource: true,
    zone: true,
    contractor: true,
    responsible_person: true,
  },
};
```

this is my html table in my vue page

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="tblOne">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Punkt</th>
                    <th>Kräv</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Resurs</td>
                    <td>
                      <p-check
                        class="p-switch p-bigger"
                        color="warning"
                        id="resource"
                        v-model="this.project_settings.resource"
                      ></p-check>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Zone</td>
                    <td>
                      <p-check
                        class="p-switch p-bigger"
                        color="warning"
                        id="zone"
                        v-model="this.project_settings.zone"
                      ></p-check>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Contractor</td>
                    <td>
                      <p-check
                        class="p-switch p-bigger"
                        color="warning"
                        id="contractor"
                        v-model="this.project_settings.contractor"
                      ></p-check>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Responsible person</td>
                    <td>
                      <p-check
                        class="p-switch p-bigger"
                        color="warning"
                        id="responsible_person"
                        v-model="this.project_settings.responsible_person"
                      ></p-check>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry don't have the reputation to comment, Im not quite sure, but could you try without this.project_settings? So only project_settings, because i think its because your component is not yet intialized